# Understanding integration on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $S^{n-1}$ be the unit sphere in
$\mathbb{R}^n$ $(n \ge 2)$ equipped with the normalized Lebesgue measure
$d\sigma=d\sigma(x')$. Suppose that $\Omega \in Lip_{\alpha}(S^{n-1})~(0<\alpha\leq 1)$, i.e.
$$
|\Omega(x^\prime)-\Omega(y^\prime)|\leq C |x^\prime-y^\prime|^{\alpha},\qquad x^\prime, y^\prime\in S^{n-1}.
$$

Let $h$ be a measurable function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. By the conditions on $\Omega$ can we write the following inequality ?
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\Omega(x-y)||h(y)|dy\leq C \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|h(y)|dy.
$$

My opinion is since $\Omega \in Lip_{\alpha}(S^{n-1})$, $\Omega$ is bounded on $S^{n-1}$. But the integral is taken on whole space. So we can not write that inequality.

Can we do something with using spherical coordinates ?

Comment: I think you need that $h$ has compact support in $S^{n-1}$.

Comment: Maybe you want to look at $\Omega(\frac{x-y}{|x-y|})$?

Comment: @Irddo ? - $S^{n-1}$  _is_ compact.

Comment: I meant $h=0$ in $R^n-S^{n-1},$ i.e, $supp_{\Bbb{R}^n} {h}\subset S^{n-1}.$

Comment: @Irddo Then the integral is $=0$ since $S^{n-1}$ is a set of measure $0$.

Comment: @Thomas you mean that "the inequality is wrong under given conditions." Am i right ?